# Web Scraping tag of html in Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I would like to scrape all the links that end with *.php*
I have written a regrex to select the target url such as **samsung-phones-f-9-0-r1-p1.php**

I am wondering if there's something wrong with my regrex or the tag is not correct.

Thank you so much in advance for answering

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request as urlopen
import ssl 
import re

base_url = 'https://www.gsmarena.com/samsung-phones-9.php'
webrequest = request.Request(url, headers = {
    "User-Agent" : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.101 Safari/537.36'})
    
    
# open the url
html = request.urlopen(base_url).read().decode('utf-8')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features = 'lxml')
# scraping sub urls
sub_urls = soup.find_all('a', {"href": re.compile("(samsung).+(.php)")})
# https:\/\/www\.gsmarena\.com\/samsung.+(.php)
print(sub_urls)
```

[image: The wrong result is demonstrated in bellow]

Comment: What is the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it right but you are not extracting the actual href property from the  tags.
Modify this line:

```
sub_urls = soup.find_all('a', {"href": re.compile("(samsung).+(.php)")})
```

to this:

```
sub_urls = [x.get('href') for x in soup.find_all('a', {"href": re.compile("(samsung).+(.php)")})]
```

Comment: Could I ask why it needs a get() to return href?
I thought if I specified "href" and all the "href" tags would be selected.

Comment: anything specified within find_all() function would help narrow down the tag selection. this is why your find_all function was returning list of <a> tags. To get any attribute of selected tags, you must use .get() function and specify the key you need.

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression is not exactly wrong, since it will capture the URLs you are aiming for. However, two points to consider: (1) the parenthesis are unnecessary and (2) you should escape the `.` character in `.php`, or it'll be compiled as a quantifier. A better solution might look like this: `samsung.+\.php`. Of course this is will only capture the .php file itself and not the whole URL. If wanted the whole thing you'd have to use `.*samsung.+\.php`.
You can always use an [online tool](https://regex101.com/) to test your regular expressions.

Either way, you haven't outlined any concrete issues, therefore I'm not sure if I've satisfied your doubts.

Comment: I have tried the online tool that shows the paired result is okay, I suspect the problem is html tags.